# What is all the research direction of physics？

Tags: education

All the research direction of physics is a large branch and a potential research direction

Answer (score 1):

The objective of physics is to cast the functioning of our universe in mathematical form so that concrete numerical predictions can be made, problems solved, and the history of physics explained.

The current topics of physics research can be divided into two classes: the very small (quantum physics) and the very large (astrophysics and cosmology). The very small is explored with particle accelerators (which can be thought of as extremely high-powered microscopes) and the very large is explored with telescopes which operate in a variety of wavelength ranges.

We know that at very early times in the lifetime of our universe, the scale of the universe was small, and in this sense the highest-energy accelerators are time machines which allow us to re-create conditions that existed back then.

One of the fundamental problems of physics is to mathematically model the merging of quantum mechanics with cosmology, which centers on Einstein's models of relativity.
So far, no one knows exactly how to accomplish this- which is a task that, when completed, will be the stuff of Nobel prizes.